# Why Ljung box test return NA for Q and hence p-value when residual is 0 (in R)

Tags: r, time-series

Just like the question title.
I have done Ljung box tests in R for model fitting in time-series with constant values (i.e.: 0), and I got perfect model fit and 0 residuals with no surprise. But I want to know why the test returns NA for Q and p-value instead of for example p=0.99999 or something like that.
I want to have a theoretical interpretation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using stats::Box.test() you can take a look at the code yourself:

```
utils::getAnywhere(Box.test)
```

The Ljung-Box Q-statistics is NaN because

```
cor <- acf (x, lag.max = lag, plot = FALSE, na.action = na.pass)
```

already returns NaN. So the subsequent computations

```
obs <- cor$acf[2:(lag+1)]

STATISTIC <- n*(n+2)*sum(1/seq.int(n-1, n-lag)*obs^2)
```

are NaN too - and so on. So it seems like you should look at stats::acf() what's going on in there ...

```
utils::getAnywhere(acf)
```

You should also be able to find the code on Github.